# Problem with exec in PHP

Tags: php, exec

I am running through a weird problem with exec's in PHP. When I load in the browser the script x.php, the browser hangs and when I run a *ps* I can see multiple threads being created. The only way to stop them is by restarting apache.

However, instead of running a php script, if I do something like *system('ls')*, it works fine. So it seems to be problem when a PHP script tries to run another script using exec/system/passthru (I've tried them all).

x.php is defined as following:

```
<?php
var_dump(system('php -f t.php'));
?>
```

t.php is defined as following:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

Comment: So far, my solution was to write to a file where I have a inotify cronjob that checks for changes and run a php script. It's not the best solution, but it's something I had to come up while I try to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [first comment in exec() manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#102342).

Comment: I have tried that already.. I still get infinite threads. I am guessing it's something I have to do on how Apache *talks* to PHP or vice-versa?

Comment: It may be. What system are you working on and how does Apache talk to PHP (ISAPI, CGI)?
If you just want to intercept output of script, include it and use output buffering.